# use of builtin function n with summarize_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting a basic dplyr::summarize_if on a df with the built-in n function:

```
###Seems like this should work
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(n, mean, sd, min, max), na.rm = TRUE)  

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : `n()` does not take arguments
```

```
###Works fine without the n

df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, sd, min, max), na.rm = TRUE)  
A tibble: 1 x 104
```

I've tried `n()` and `n(.)` (which of course wouldn't expect to work and don't).

Any secret I'm missing to using `funs(n)` in a `summarise_if`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `n()` is expecting a `data.frame`, whereas the functions within `funs(...)` will be passed vectors. Perhaps `length`? (Probably not what you want ... you want a single `n` variable, I think ...)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, great point. Alas, indeed, I tried length and also count with errors on both (length says its receiving two arguments).

Comment: @BenjaminGowan - you'd need to make a new `length()` which can handle (and ignore) other arguments - `len <- function(x,...) length(x)` for instance. Though it would still repeat for each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a single-pass operation to summarize in two different ways. You want to summarize (1) the number of rows (perhaps per-group); and (2) specific functions for certain columns. The `n()` helper function tends to expect to be employed on a *full-`data.frame`*, whereas the functions identified within `funs(...)` will all be passed a vector at a time.

One method would be to merge/join in what you need. Since you didn't provide data, I'll use `mtcars`. Though you don't mention grouping, I'm guessing that there may be groups (though it doesn't complicate things), so I'll inject that, too:

```
library(dplyr)
counts <- select(mtcars, cyl, mpg, wt) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  count()
counts
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#     cyl     n
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     4    11
# 2     6     7
# 3     8    14
```

(`count()` is essentially a shortcut for `summarize(n = n())`. This could have been done with `select(mtcars, cyl, mpg, wt) %>% count(cyl)` just as easily, but I wanted the grouping to be explicit for this answer.)

```
others <- select(mtcars, cyl, mpg, wt) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, sd))
others
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#     cyl mpg_mean  wt_mean   mpg_sd     wt_sd
#   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     4 26.66364 2.285727 4.509828 0.5695637
# 2     6 19.74286 3.117143 1.453567 0.3563455
# 3     8 15.10000 3.999214 2.560048 0.7594047

left_join(counts, others, by = "cyl")
# # A tibble: 3 × 6
#     cyl     n mpg_mean  wt_mean   mpg_sd     wt_sd
#   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     4    11 26.66364 2.285727 4.509828 0.5695637
# 2     6     7 19.74286 3.117143 1.453567 0.3563455
# 3     8    14 15.10000 3.999214 2.560048 0.7594047
```

This could of course be done in one-fell-swoop instead of creating the intermediate variables `counts` and `others`, but (1) I thought it would be more demonstrative to break them out; and (2) sometimes clarity in code is preferred to compactness. One could add `%>% left_join(counts, by = "cyl")` to the end of the `others` pipeline, though, with no loss of clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm brand new to stack overflow, I'm mark this as an answer soon as I figure out how!

Comment: (There should be a checkmark to the left of the answer, immediately below the vote-up/down arrows.)

Answer (score 3):

`n()` can work in a `summarise_if`

```
 mtcars %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(n()))

  # mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  32  32   32 32   32 32   32 32 32   32   32
```

Your problem arises because you're silently passing `na.rm=TRUE` to it

```
mtcars %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(n(na.rm=TRUE)))
# Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : `n()` does not take arguments
```

**Hack solution**

Since you lose information with summarise, you'll need to summarise independently with `n()` and `(mean, median, max, min), na.rm=TRUE`. You can `cbind` the results

```
N <- mtcars %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(n()))
stats <- mtcars %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, median, max, min), na.rm=TRUE)
cbind(N,stats)

  # mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb mpg_mean cyl_mean disp_mean  hp_mean drat_mean wt_mean qsec_mean vs_mean am_mean
# 1  32  32   32 32   32 32   32 32 32   32   32 20.09062   6.1875  230.7219 146.6875  3.596563 3.21725  17.84875  0.4375 0.40625
  # gear_mean carb_mean mpg_median cyl_median disp_median hp_median drat_median wt_median qsec_median vs_median am_median
# 1    3.6875    2.8125       19.2          6       196.3       123       3.695     3.325       17.71         0         0
  # gear_median carb_median mpg_max cyl_max disp_max hp_max drat_max wt_max qsec_max vs_max am_max gear_max carb_max mpg_min
# 1           4           2    33.9       8      472    335     4.93  5.424     22.9      1      1        5        8    10.4
  # cyl_min disp_min hp_min drat_min wt_min qsec_min vs_min am_min gear_min carb_min
# 1       4     71.1     52     2.76  1.513     14.5      0      0        3        1
```

Comment: Your first example is not demonstrating that `n()` can deal with vectors. The second example is clearer, and though I'm surprised it works as it does, I don't think it meets the summarizing needs of the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I thought OP was simply looking for an explanation. I've edited my answer to provide a solution. You're right about the first example. I've deleted it. Thanks!