# Generate summarise function parameters using a loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a data looks like this.

```
data = data.frame(GENDER = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2"),
                  ZSCORE_0 = c(12.12, 12.67, 13.72, 13.79, 14.78),
                  ZSCORE_3 = ...,
                  ZSCORE_6 = ...,
                  ...
                  ZSCORE = 60 = ...)
```

I tried summarizing this data using summarise function in dplyr package.

I have a problem that is too many parameters.

For example

```
data %>%
    group_by(GENDER) %>%
    summarise(MIN_ZSCORE_0 = min(ZSCORE_0),
              MIN_ZSCORE_3 = min(ZSCORE_3),
              ...,
              MIN_ZSCORE_60 = min(ZSCORE_60),
              MAX_ZSCORE_0 = max(ZSCORE_0),
              MAX_ZSCORE_3 = max(ZSCORE_3),
              ...,
              MAX_ZSCORE_60 = max(ZSCORE_60),
              MEAN,
              MEDIAN,
              n,
              ...)
```

I want to simplify this work.

I used a loop to create parameters.

```
interval = seq(3, 60, 3)

data %>%
    group_by(GENDER) %>%
    summarise(for (i in interval) {
                  target = paste0("ZSCORE_", i)
                  min(target)
                  max(target)
                  ...
                  n(target)
              })
```

However it does not work.

```
Error: Column `for (... in NULL) NULL` is of unsupported type NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use loop inside `summarise`. However, try using `summarise_all`:

```
require(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  summarise_all(c("min", "max"))
```

Result:

```
  mpg_min cyl_min disp_min hp_min drat_min wt_min qsec_min
1    10.4       4     71.1     52     2.76  1.513     14.5
  vs_min am_min gear_min carb_min mpg_max cyl_max disp_max
1      0      0        3        1    33.9       8      472
  hp_max drat_max wt_max qsec_max vs_max am_max gear_max
1    335     4.93  5.424     22.9      1      1        5
  carb_max
1        8
```

## Edit

Their is a problem in using `n()` inside `summarise_all`/`summarise_if` because it automatically tries to force the argument `na.rm = TRUE` into `n()`. Which in turn raise an error, as `n()` doesn't have this argument. However, you can you use this hack (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229317/use-of-builtin-function-n-with-summarize-if)):

```
require(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, c("min", "max")) %>% 
  cbind(summarise_if(mtcars, is.numeric, funs(n())))
```

Result:

```
  mpg_min cyl_min disp_min hp_min drat_min wt_min qsec_min
1    10.4       4     71.1     52     2.76  1.513     14.5
  vs_min am_min gear_min carb_min mpg_max cyl_max disp_max
1      0      0        3        1    33.9       8      472
  hp_max drat_max wt_max qsec_max vs_max am_max gear_max
1    335     4.93  5.424     22.9      1      1        5
  carb_max mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
1        8  32  32   32 32   32 32   32 32 32   32   32
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask a one more question? How to use "n" with "min" and "max" in summarise_all() function?